# Trying to get a better understanding of ViewModel with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to understand how the binding works with MVC.

Say I have this model.

```
public class MyObjectModel
{        
        public int MyID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Add1 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
}
```

In my case I have a controller that just returns a View(). (No model).

However in my view I have grid that makes a call back to the controller and returns a list. `List<MyObjectModel> listObject`

Now in this grid each row is a MyObjectModel.  So the user goes and either creates or modifies a MyObjectModel object.

When the user clicks save there is a post method.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public void CreateMyObject([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, MyObjectModel obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {               
        // Go update the database
    }            
}
```

How does the binding work from initially sending the data to the view and from the view back to the controller?  
Can I manually manipulate (via Jquery) the MyObjectModel prior to posting it back to the controller?

Obviously I am having an issue passing data back to the controller, but if had a better understanding how the binding work in general I should hopefully be able to learn as well as resolve my issue.

Comment: if you want to understand ViewModels: [Use ViewModels to manage data & organize code in ASP.NET MVC applications](http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/)

Comment: if you want to understand ASP.NET Model Binding: [Introduction to ASP.NET MVC Model Binding - An Absolute Beginner's Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyObjectModel` only ever exists on the server.

You use its properties to help generate HTML text via a View (`blahblah.cshtml`). The View will usually have a form, and (via the eerie, inhuman magic of the `HtmlHelper` stuff) the form fields will be given values in their attributes based on properties in `MyObjectModel`. Then the server sends that HTML as text (a long series of zeroes and ones) through a wire to the client browser.

On the client, the browser renders the HTML page you send it. In that page, there may be JavaScript, which can manipulate form fields in the page, but it can't touch any C# code that exists in a different computer on the other side of the Internet.

When the user submits the form, the browser posts form field values, in the form of text (another long sequence of zeroes and ones) back to the server, which creates a brand new fresh instance of `MyObjectModel` and initializes it with the form field values from the client, and hands it to your Controller method.

Based on my past exposure to the term "view model", it isn't the right term to use with MVC (note: [Some people use the term with MVC](http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/). That's a new one on me, but I think I may wish they'd picked a different term to refer to the concept they're talking about). The term "view models" is usually used in environments like WPF, where the UI and the models exist in the same memory space, so you can have a live .NET class instance that interacts with both. You can't do that in a web application like MVC where your model lives on the server. In MVC, if you wanted something to be analagous to a view model, it would have to be written in JavaScript and run on the client.

It's important in web programming to always be cognizant of which code is on the server and which is on the client. Writing server code in C# and client code in JavaScript is a big help in that regard, I find. I've done a little classic ASP and it was too easy to get disoriented, when both ends were written in JavaScript.

You can of course write a full AJAX web application with a view model on the client, and have it use the server as a data store that it talks to via web services. But that's not what you're doing in the MVC code you included in your question.

Comment: TY for the explanation.  What would be the best way to test what is getting posted back to the controller?

Comment: @JDS [The answer is always Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)! That'll let you see the text of the form fields the browser is sending back. Fantastic, indispensable tool.

Comment: @JDS Is `CreateMyObject` getting called when you post the form from the browser? If you put in a breakpoint, what do you see in `dsRequest` and `obj`?

Comment: CreateMyObject has all of the fields populated but 1.  It is a dropdown list that is set as a template. It works fine if a user edits an existing record and changes it, however a new record will return null back even though a value was selected.  I'll try fiddlr to see what I can see.

Comment: @JDS I think the usual thing is to have a different view and controller method for creating new records. This is MVC4; are you in 4 or 5? http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part6

Comment: MVC5 - The template was Kendo's suggestion to add a dropdown to a grid cell.  However I'm still not getting the desired results go I'll try to debug it further with Fiddlr